# What happened to the L4 cache?

Tags: caching, memory, optimization, intel, cpu-architecture

There isn't a lot of information about the L4 cache, but as far as I know, it was used in the 4th and 5th generation of Intel processors(2013-2014), but it's gone from the current generation.

Was the L4 bad, ineffective or something?

Comment: There are Skylake CPUs with eDRAM L4, e.g. i5 6350HQ.  See the L4 column on [Wikipedia's table of SKL CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)#Mobile_processors_.28See_also_.22Server.2C_Mobile.22_below.29).  The only socketed desktop CPUs with eDRAM were Broadwell, and frustratingly Intel hasn't announced a desktop SKL with eDRAM.  :(

Comment: The interesting change to L4 in SKL is that it's now a memory-side cache, instead of a victim-cache for L3.  See the eDRAM section of [Anandtech's article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/9582/intel-skylake-mobile-desktop-launch-architecture-analysis/5) for example.

Comment: @Axel1212 actually the L4 cache is present on all cpu of the ibm system z architecture. The z15 from 2019 has 960Mb of L4 cache as an exemple.

Answer (score 3):

For Haswell and Broadwell, eDRAM L4 cache tags are resident in the on-chip L3 cache. Although this setup simplifies the LLC design and allows earlier tag checking for fetches from the processor, it makes the accessing to eDRAM LLC from other devices (e.g., independent GPUs via PCIe) slower as these memory requests have to be forwarded to on-chip L3 first before being handled by the LLC. To address this, eDRAM has been moved to the position upon DRAM controllers in Skylake (more like a memory-side buffer rather than a cache)

Reference : Li, Ang, et al. "Exploring and analyzing the real impact of modern on-package memory on HPC scientific kernels." Proceedings of the International Conference for High Performance Computing, Networking, Storage and Analysis. ACM, 2017

You can see Broadwell, Haswell, and Skylake architectures below.
[image: Intel Broadwell and Haswell micro arch.]
Broadwell and Haswell

[image: Intel Skylake micro arch.]
Skylake

Comment: The L4 tags are still on-die in Skylake, as I understand it.  They're separate, not stealing space away from the per-core L3 slices, but still on the main die, not the eDRAM die, as I understand it.

Comment: I think you are right. It seems to me that eDRAM CTL (in Skylake) is the actual location to compare tags and control eDRAM and it is in CPU die. eDRAM and CPU are not in the same die but in the same package and they are connected by a high-bandwidth link called On-Package I/O (OPIO). Since this link is a shared resource to forward memory requests of all cores (+ Iris GPU) and highly under contention, it makes sense to use it only for hit requests. In the other words, it is more reasonable to first check the tags in CPU die (no bandwidth contention) and only use the link for hit requests.

Comment: Yes, the eDRAM is definitely in the same package, but not the same silicon die.  The manufacturing process for DRAM is different from what you want for high-speed logic like a CPU.

Comment: And yes, keeping tag-checks on the main die makes a lot of sense. 
 However, I think the eDRAM is used as a write-back cache for DDR, so write misses will often result in flushing a different line back to DDR and writing the new data into the eDRAM.  (I think the GPU drivers can generate requests that go around eDRAM, but normal CPU load/store is backstopped by L4 eDRAM.)

Comment: I think eDRAM process technology is similar to the logic and this is the reason that makes it faster but not area efficient(compared to DRAM). The reason that it is not on the same die is that the way intel builds it to be cheaper. However, IBM builds them in the same die as CPU.

Comment: Both IBM and Intel adopt DRAM-cell based eDRAM design in their recent processors. However, unlike IBM that digs trench capacitors into the silicon substrate of the main processor chip, Intel fills the metal-insulatormetal (MIM) trench capacitors above the transistors, and fabricates an isolated chip. Such fabrication simplifies the manufacturing process and reduces cost.

Comment: Interesting.  I found http://semiengineering.com/the-power-of-edram/ from 2014 comparing Haswell eDRAM vs. Power7 / Power8.  Looks like IBM went for a higher-performance on-chip eDRAM, while Intel still uses large fast SRAM L3 caches and maybe doesn't *need* as high eDRAM performance.  Using the same main die for SKUs with/without eDRAM is of course a huge reason for Intel to keep the eDRAM itself on a separate die, as long as the performance is still viable.  Good point that we shouldn't conclude to much from that.