# Which factor contribute most to make SRAM much faster than DRAM

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

I read several articles as well as textbook. But they are ambiguous about this topic - Which factor contributes most to make SRAM much faster than DRAM? One ore more among the following? Or any other factors?

1) The capacity of DRAM is much higher than SRAM which takes longer for DRAM to address the target memory cells.

2) The electricity component that consist the DRAM and SRAM. The DRAM uses a capacitor and a access transistor while the SRAM uses 6 transistors. The charging of capacitor takes longer than just switching on/off SRAM transistors.

3) The need to periodically refresh the DRAM in order to conquer the leakage increase the access latency (The access can't happen when the DRAM is under refreshing)

Comment: First, DRAM and SRAM and *types* of memory technologies. There are many different implementations of each with wildly varying and complex performance characteristics. Second, it seems that you are mixing between the inherent characteristics of a single (DRAM or SRAM) memory cell and the architectural design of a whole memory module. So your question is *extremely* open-ended. Read the Wikipedia articles on SRAM and DRAM and then edit your question to make it as specific as you can so that it can be answered with less than a thousand words.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you wanted to, you could build a *fairly* fast DRAM, e.g. [for the on-die eDRAM that POWER8 uses for L3 cache.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864852/what-happened-to-the-l4-cache/49643317?noredirect=1#comment86376809_49643317)

But it can't quite be as fast as SRAM, for various reasons including that the charge on the tiny capacitor can't drive a big load the way the transistors in an SRAM can.  (This might be a tiny fraction of the total access time for DRAM, I'm not an expect on things that low level; you might want to re-ask this on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Thus, simply looking at existing SRAM / DRAM in real chips has some sample bias: if perf requirements are low enough that DRAM is an option, designers may use eDRAM for the density advantage, for a large array.  Or for performance, using SRAM may be easier / better than heavily optimizing eDRAM for speed.  But POWER8 definitely has fast L3 DRAM; [aggregate bandwidth of 3TB/s across 12 cores @ 4GHz](http://semiengineering.com/the-power-of-edram/).

(Small microcontrollers with under 1 kiB of on-chip SRAM probably use SRAM because it doesn't need any refresh circuitry, and other overhead that doesn't pay off for tiny eDRAM arrays.  Not to mention potential access delays from refresh, which is not good for hard realtime systems where you want to know exactly how long things take.)

Comment: eDRAM also often requires extra process steps or different process optimization, so for small memory arrays in cost sensitive chips SRAM is typically a better choice. Density also affects whether a given amount of storage will fit on a single chip with computational elements; off-chip access introduces latency and bandwidth disadvantages. (I seem to recall that IBM's POWER8 used capacitors for voltage droop protection, so not all the extra process cost need be attributed to eDRAM [or once trench capacitors were to be used for eDRAM, they became available for other uses].)

Answer (score 1):

The #1 factor that makes DRAM slower than SRAM is the fact DRAM uses a capacitor.

I am confused by your 3 points so just in case someone else stumbles upon this question let me clarify what's happening in "general," inside of SRAM and DRAM, so the programmer minded person can understand why this question is on Stack Overflow.

The use of a capacitor in DRAM means every ~64ms the capacitor must be "refreshed" during which time memory access is not possible, because doing a refresh is simply a read operation.

I really like how Ulrich Drepper describes the two in [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf) where he explains the primary reason we use DRAM more rather than SRAM is cost. SRAM is more expensive to produce & use!

This is the 6 transistors that make up SRAM:
[image]

> The core of this cell is formed by the four transistors M1 to M4 which form two cross-coupled inverters. They have two stable states, representing 0 and 1 respectively. The state is stable as long as power on Vdd is available

The other two transistors are M5 & M6 which I'll go into in a moment, as well as how to write to SRAM but first let's take a look at the DRAM cell:

[image]

Here we have 1 transistor which acts as a guard to the state of the cell being held in the capacitor. So to access the value in this cell one would raise the access line (AL) and the value of the capacitor is placed on the data line(DL). To write or refresh the value is placed on the DL and AL needs to activate long enough to charge or drain the capacitor.

As you can imagine this takes time compared to SRAM where the value is "static" thus S in SRAM. Once the word access line (WL) is raised a read is immediately available. Writing is almost as simple in SRAM, the corresponding values are placed on BL and

> Since the outside drivers are stronger than the four transistors (M1 through M4) this allows the old state to be overwritten

DRAM requires a "sense amplifier" to make the DL readable because the capacitor can only hold so much of a charge, thus the need for such periodic refreshes. Once filled, those electrons slowly dissipate over time, a concept known as "leakage." The capacitor will also need recharged every time a read occurs b/c simply the act of reading will drain it.

To wrap up, what makes this a Stack Overflow question? Well Drepper says:

> There is really not much the programmer can do about the refresh and the points in time when the commands are issued. But it is important to keep this part of the DRAM life cycle in mind when interpreting measurements. If a critical word has to be retrieved from a row which currently is being refreshed the processor could be stalled for quite a long time. How long each refresh takes depends on the DRAM module

Now Drepper wrote this in 2007, sometime after, people started to manipulate the memory controller (Memory controllers contain the logic necessary to read and write to DRAM, and to "refresh" the DRAM). One result is this amazing mechanism called ChargeCache that I'll leave a link to right here: https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~omutlu/pub/chargecache_low-latency-dram_hpca16.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your point number 3:-
Let me explain DRAM is called dynamic ram because it has 1 capacitor(which stores charge i.e full charge means 1 and empty means 0) and 1 transistor(act as a switch which fully charges and discharges the capacitor) and there are many pair of such capacitor and transistor in DRAM. Now, the problem is that the capacitor always leaks the charge stored inside it so there is a constant requirement of dynamically charging the capacitor which is holding the charge(value 1) to maintain it's charge which is done 1000's of time per sec which make the DRAM slow.